# Using Kestrel Without IIS and VS 2017

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Dependent on Microsoft Documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Kestrel can be used by itself or with a reverse proxy server, such as IIS, Nginx, or Apache. A reverse proxy server receives HTTP requests from the Internet and forwards them to Kestrel after some preliminary handling.

IIS, Nginx, and Apache can't be used without Kestrel or a custom server implementation. ASP.NET Core was designed to run in its own process so that it can behave consistently across platforms.

But when i run the visual studio 2017, always IIS Express runs. So how to depend on kestrel alone if that is possible dependent on MS documentation.

Comment: Did you try changing the execution Profile from IIS Express to the one named after your startup project on the run dropdown?

Comment: kindly provide more details on the execution profiles and its affect on the startup config does any thing require changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the startup application from the toolbar in VS2017

[image]

In the example above Visual Studio will host my app in IIS Express (the item with the tick). If you want to run it as a Kestrel hosted application then I would select `WebApplication2` from the drop down. Now, when I start the application it will run from a command prompt window.

If you are using .NET Core 2.0 then your `Program.cs` file should look something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }
}
```

Behind the scenes (in the `Build()` method) ASP.NET Core will add the calls to ensure you app will run within IIS and Kestrel without you needing to change anything.

Comment: My VS does not have this option in the menu bar (I probably removed it previously). What's it called so I can re-add it?