# Recommended server when running ASP.NET Core web apps in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

Having a hard time finding the right doc for this particular feature.

Under the green arrow (launch profiles dropdown list) in Visual Studio 2017 I have a menu item named after my project. Is this the Kestrel server option? Is it the default? Is this option (Kestrel) the recommended one to use for ASP.NET Core 2.1 web apps? Is IIS Express considered obsolete?

I think it is a little bit annoying really that there are so many options to choose from. Specially when there's no quick explanation in the IDE and you don't know which is which. It's like having three play buttons in Spotify each doing the same thing but with different names on them. So which one do I click?

Comment: There's also self-hosted", IIS/NGINX as a reverse proxy, IIS/NGINX as an actual host. That's the point - there's no recommended server. You can use ASP.NET Core with a *lot* of servers. Different servers provide *different* features, benefits etc. IIS Express isn't obsolete - it's was alwasy meant for development. IIS, the only production option before .NET Core isn't obsolete either. You don't need to use it if you don't want its features though.

Comment: Yes, but for Visual Studio there's got to be one that is better/faster/more modern than the others for instance when debugging. Production servers is a completely different story and yes you can basically use whichever server you like publicly with ASP.NET Core. And you have to think not only for yourself but for beginners and people new to the IDEs in general. They will have no idea what these different options are. I guess I'm trying to say this is not the best of UX.

Comment: IIS (and by extension IIS Express) can only act as a reverse proxy right now. Hosting *inside* IIS is still an experimental feature. Which means you'll use Kestrel anyway. If you intend to deploy to IIS, you should configure your project to use IIS or IIS Express.

Comment: You can do both through configuration. You can check eg an environment variable or command-line parameter and use different configuration methods for each case. This would allow you to quickly test your code using only Kestrel in most scenarios and use IIS/IIS Express for debugging/testing in conditions similar to production

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to read these docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

> ASP.NET Core ships two server implementations:
>
> Kestrel is the default, cross-platform HTTP server for ASP.NET Core.
>
> HTTP.sys is a Windows-only HTTP server based on the HTTP.sys kernel
>   driver and HTTP Server API. (HTTP.sys is called WebListener in ASP.NET
>   Core 1.x.)

[image]

[image]

In simple words ASP.NET Core runs its own HTTP server. Than you can use IIS, IIS Express, Nginx, Apache as reverse proxy.

When you run ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio you can run in two modes:

1. Without debugging - it fires up Krestrel and IIS Express.
2. With debugging - it only fires up Krestrel

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: The default for me is IIS Express. I have a clean install of VS 2017. Is there a way to reset the default web server launch profile?

Comment: Also, just read the following article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-2.1
"Visual Studio starts IIS Express and runs the app." which is confusing since Razor Pages is supposed to be the new way of building ASP.NET Core web apps and I would expect running a Razor Pages web app using Kestrel and not IIS Express?

Comment: Here is an example of running Krestrel without IIS in VS: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50351849/275882

Comment: @PussInBoots: 1) Kestrel is not a full web server. It's sufficient for a lot of things, but you'll almost always want to use it as a reverse proxy behind a true web server like IIS, nginx, Apache, etc. It's not a replacement for other full web servers. 2) Don't drink the Kool-aid. Razor Pages are not the "new way of building ASP.NET Core web apps". The are just *one* way to do so, and frankly a pretty sub-par way at that. If you have a simplistic sight that mostly does CRUD type stuff, Razor Pages may be just fine, but for anything more complex MVC is still the way to go.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "When you run ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio by default it fires up Krestrel and IIS Express."? This means one or the other or they are both used at the same time?

Comment: Also, reading the docs, this is also confusing; "When using Visual Studio, Visual Studio for Mac, or Visual Studio Code, the server is launched when the app is started by the Integrated Development Environment (IDE). In Visual Studio on Windows, launch profiles can be used to start the app and server with either IIS Express/ASP.NET Core Module or the console." "the server" - which server? "or the console" - are they referring to Kestrel? Very confusing.

Comment: @ArturKedzior that is basically the info I was looking for but where can I find it on Microsofts website? In no article have I managed to find an explanation about the launch profile named after your project, and that it corresponds to Kestrel. If anyone knows where to find it please share.

Comment: Yes. VS fires up Krestrel on port 5000 (by default) than fires up IIS Express that automatically configures to work as reverse-proxy. Think of Krestrel as an application server that is limited and its main purpose is to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Correction it fires up both when in non-debug mode, fires only Krestrel if in debug mode.

Comment: @ChrisPratt yeah, that's what I been reading up on lately because that is  one concern that I have with Razor Pages, that it could a new Web Forms not staying for that long. It's interesting though how Microsoft already is referring to it as the recommended / best (seen/heard it in a couple of microsoft docs and videos) way for new ASP.NET Core web apps. There's nothing from preventing you from using both MVC and Razor Pages however so this might be the ultimate way in the future. I think only time will tell.

Comment: @ArturKedzior okay, didn't know that it fired up both in non-debug mode. You know where one might find such a piece of information? Should be somewhere in the ASP.NET Core 2.1 docs, yes? Or in the Visual Studio 2017 docs? Or in both?

Comment: @PussInBoots It's marketing, mostly. It looks good in demos because it's so "easy", until you need to build something more complicated and it falls down. Just take a scan at Razor Pages related questions on this site and you can easily see that the majority are things that are downright easy and basic with MVC. It's all about using the right tool for the job.